# Replace strings with more than one character

Tags: regex, replace, sed

I have a text file like the one shown below:

```
A B
A D
S F
D TGT
DS K
FDGFDA S
A RE
```

I want to replace all strings with more than one character (so "TGT", "DS", "FDGFDA" and "RE" above) with a single character (e.g. "X").

Is there a way to do this? It seems like something sed should do easily, but I can't work out the regex string to use to do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the Regex:

```
\w{2,}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/OSsX3IuXKg6MY465)

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
sed 's/^[[:alnum:]]\{2,\}/X/' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to both who answered my question: I found a way with another regex:

```
sed -i 's/[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]*/X/g'
```

Comment: you should be able to shorten it to `sed -i 's/[A-Z]\{2,\}/X/g'`